# Code deploy from Bitbucket to AWS S3 bucket through Teamcity

Tags: amazon-s3, teamcity, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I am trying make some Continuous Integration in Teamcity. Which is deploying code from Bitbucket to AWS s3 bucket.

We have a repository in bitbucket and it contains couple of folders as 
[image]

I just need to deploy this **build** folder with all the contents in it to the AWS and inside one of the S3 Bucket Repository.

We can overwrite the existing copy of Build Folder which is already existing in the S3 bucket Repo.

My initial approach was i have to create a **IAM** user or a role with sufficient permissions for TeamCity to access AWS services

I need to install a AWS code deploy plugin in Teamcity.

But my only question is that how can i get the code from Bitbucket to Teamcity and deploy in AWS bucket.

Is there anyway around Please do the need full to me..
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Did you look at this blog https://stiltsoft.com/blog/2016/04/how-to-integrate-teamcity-and-bitbucket-server/? You can use the either "Commit Status Publisher" or "TeamCity Stash Integration" plugins.

Comment: But my End result is to put the code in AWS s3 bucket from bitbucket.